# Cypress Automation - How to copy contents of file and use to paste in browser?

Tags: cypress

Here's the scenario I'm trying to overcome..

Using cypress, it navigates to part of the app which has an input box.
I need to open a .txt file, copy its entire contents keeping the formatting
then paste / type this into the input box in the app.

I've got

```
   cy.readFile('blah.txt').then((blah) => {
        cy.log(blah)
        cy.get('.inputBox').type(blah)
    })
```

It is reading the file fine, but it puts everything into 1 long string, where as I need the new lines to remain.

would using .split be the right way to go about it? is there an alternative?

The text file I'm using for this test is quite small and easy to manipulate but there will be tests coming up where the file is much larger or even a .xlsx

Comment: Thinking outside the box a little, but another approach tried was..

using selenium code in the plugins/index.js file
Fire up a browser
open the file
Ctrl + A
Ctrl + C
then i was hoping i could do ctrl +v in cypress however whilst the content is copied to my pc clipboard, it's not coming through in the cypress

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
cy.fixture('copy_pasta.txt').then(text => {
  cy.get('.panel-body').eq(0).clear().type(text)
        })
```

Here is fixture() documentation: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture